# Two coordinates, two angles, and the third coordinate

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be points on a two-dimensional coordinate system. Assume $A=(0,1), B=(0,5)$, angle $\alpha$ of $A$ is 47 degrees, and angle $\beta$ of $B$ is 80 degrees.

Calculate the coordinates of C to one decimal place.

To show effort: I can use the law of sines to find out that $AC = 4.9$, and $BC = 3.7$. But I have no idea how to pinpoint coordinate $C$ without using precise tools, which, I assume, isn't the point. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Having got $AC$, you have that the $x$-coordinate of $C$ is $AC\sin\alpha$. Its $y$-coordinate is $1+AC\cos\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know a resource for why this is the case? I mean, where did these formulas come from? x = adjacent by sin of angle, and y = 1 + adjacent by cos of angle.

Comment: I am assuming $\angle CAB=47^o$. Let $X$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$. Then looking at the triangle $CAX$, you have $AC\cos 47^o=AX$. So the $y$-coordinate of $X$ is $1+AC\cos 47^o$. But $X$ and $C$ have the same $y$-coordinate.

Comment: Bear with me, I was following you perfectly until the y-coordinate conclusion. How did we conclude that, because AC cos 47 = AX, the y-coordinate of X is 1 + AC cos 47?

Answer (score 1):

- Before going into detail, a general remark: Given points $O:=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $E:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and an angle $\varphi:=\angle EOP$ ($\varphi$ is the oriented angle from $E$ to $P$ centered in $O$), the point $P$ has the coordinates $\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi\\\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$. Moreover, the distance $\overline{OP}$ is $1$. These are very central facts in geometry.
- Therefore, the distance between points $O$ and $t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi\\\sin\varphi\end{pmatrix}$ is $t$.
- Now lets define $A':=O$, $B':=B-A$ and $C':=C-A$. So the triangle $A'B'C'$ is only a translated version of the triangle $ABC$.

  - Now lets calculate the angle $\varphi_A:=\angle EOC'$. This can be rewritten as $\varphi_A=\angle EOB'+\angle B'OC'$. We know that $\angle EOB'=90°$ (take a look at the position of the points $A$ and $B$!) and we know that $\angle B'OC'=47°$. So $\varphi_A=137°$.
  - Therefore, the point $C'$ must fulfill the equation $C'=t\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi_A\\\sin\varphi_A\end{pmatrix}$ for a yet unknown parameter $t$ that represents its distance to $O$. By adding $A$ on both sides, we get $C=A+C'=A+t\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi_A\\\sin\varphi_A\end{pmatrix}$.
- With the same method as above, you can get the equation $C=B+s\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi_B\\\sin\varphi_B\end{pmatrix}$, where $\varphi_B:=270°-80°=190°$.
- One method for solving the original problem is solving the equation
  $A+t\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi_A\\\sin\varphi_A\end{pmatrix}=B+s\begin{pmatrix}\cos \varphi_B\\\sin\varphi_B\end{pmatrix}$.
  All values except $s$ and $t$ are known, and by splitting the equation into an equation for the $x$-coordinate and an equation for an $y$-coordinate, you get a system of two linear equations with two unknowns, which is solvable.
- But there is an easier method: We already said that $t=\overline{AC}$. So you can simple calculate $\overline{AC}$ (which you actually already did).
- The solution is $C=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}\cos 137°\\\sin 137°\end{pmatrix}\approx\begin{pmatrix}-3{.}6\\4{.}4\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I'm trying to wrap my mind around this without a diagram, but will probably need to try and draw it to understand it. In the meantime, I'm not used to the vertical way of writing coordinates; I understand that the top coordinate is x and lower coordinate is y. Is this true?

Comment: I've read and re-read the first paragraph about the central fact, and could not understand it at all. Then, moving to the following paragraph, I don't understand where t came from. Thus, I'm hopelessly confused now.

Comment: If you don't like writing the coordinates in a vertical way, you can write them any way you want. (The notation is irrelevant, what is relevant is the mathematics behind is!) But yes, in my notation the top coordinate is x and the lower coordinate is y. Concerning the fact I presented in the first paragraph: Maybe the following picture will help: http://www.mathe-online.at/materialien/julian.langmann/files/Winkelfunktionen_am_EHK/ehk5.png In the second paragraph, the $t$ is just a variable. I just say that if I multiply my point from the first paragraph with t, then its distance from O is t.